# Is it possible to find the latest entry of a table with "Many To One" relation without using sub query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am stuck with a problem who's solution can easily be solved by using Sub Query but it's taking too long so I'm looking for an alternate option.

Here are two tables

user

- id
- fName
- lName

transaction

- id
- user_id FK to user.id
- amount

Now, a user can have multiple transactions. If I want to get the fName, lName and the latest transaction id, latest transaction amount of the user, is it possible to do it in a single query without using sub query?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: It's MySQL v5.7

Comment: The question has been asked several times per week since Stack Overflow started. Follow the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag for many solutions. For example, here's one of mine with high upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/20860

Comment: I wasn't sure how to search and nothing I searched matched the criteria. I will check those, thanks for taking your time and linking.

Comment: ideally ids are opaque values and you should not rely on them for "latest"; if you need order, store a timestamp

Comment: To help you with this sort of question, we need to see your query, table definitions, index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. Sometimes subqueries cause performance problems, but more often they are caused by a missing index.

Comment: Ah true, actually I have the "created_at" field in my actual table. I tried to keep only the necessary fields in the question and made the mistake. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think this is not a duplicate because the question specifically asks for a method that has no subqueries.  Treating any 'with' clause, any inline view, or any other nested select as a subquery, I think there is no solution. Even windowed function which would be the preferred answer will require a subselect to reduce each group to one row.

Comment: @RobertHamilton, Did you look at the answer I linked to in my comment above? I wrote a join-based solution.

Comment: @BillKarwin  OK I give you credit for using a self join instead of subquery. I will have to modify my statement to "it is not possible without using subqueries or self joins"

Comment: @RobertHamilton LOL - so you might as well say "it's not possible without some form of SQL query." :-)